# project with wsdl2objc not compiling

Tags: iphone, libxml2

I'm following the barcode tutorial for this site: http://brismith66.blogspot.com/2010_07_01_archive.html

using the google code: http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/

I've followed the tutorial to the T and I'm having trouble getting it to compile in xcode 4.2 using the 5.0 SDK.  One of the classes (USaddtions.h) references libxml/tree.h and says the file can't be found.  Another class in the same folder I called Barcode.h refrences libxml/tree.h with no errors.

I've also tried adding the header search path /usr/include/libxml as a work around found online.  I'm new to objective-c and xcode so i'm frustrated with getting this to work.  can anyone help, or has anyone had problems getting this to compile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote those tutorials. I just opened Xcode 4.3, opened the project, went to Build Settings and changed the base SDK to iOS 5.0. I cleaned and rebuilt the project, and ran it in the emulator; no problems.

It's odd that the project appears to accept one reference to tree.xml but not the one in USAdditions.

Check your Build Settings: confirm that in "Other C Flags" you have "-I/usr/include/libxml2" specified. (That's minus sign, capital I, forwardslash, etc.)  When I was first playing with Wsdl2Objc I got burned by confusing the capital I with lowercase L

Comment: other c flags already has something in it "<Multiple Values>" if I try to add something the entire line says, ""-I/usr/include/libxml2".  should i be replacing whats there?

Comment: Looking at mine, Other C Flags says <Multiple values>; and underneath that (ie, open the group) is a place for Debug and Release. On mine, Debug says -I/usr/include/libxml2  (no quotes in the field).

Comment: thanks for all the help.  it seems to have cleared now.  i did have to comment out the @synethesize barcodedata but everything seems to be working.